# use typoscript variable in condition

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Is it possible to use variables defined in TypoScript in TypoScript conditions?

For example if I define a variable like this:

```
my_var = 10
```

Can I create a condition in typoscript that checks if `my_var` equals 10?
I imagine something like this:

```
my_var = 10
[my_var = 10]
# do something
[else]
# do something else
[end]
```

The reason why I need this is the lack of nested conditions. If what I'm asking for is possible, I can do something like this to overcome this limitation:

```
[globalVar=TSFE:id=1]
# render special layout for page 1
[else]
normal_layout = 1
[end]
[normal_layout = 1] && [globalVar=TSFE:page|layout=1]
# render normal layout 1
[end]
[normal_layout = 1] && [globalVar=TSFE:page|layout=2]
# render normal layout 2
[end]
```

Another usecase would be to check for the existence of a variable, for example if `page` was already defined. Example:

```
[globalVar=TSFE:id=1]
    page = PAGE
    page.10 = TEXT
    page.10.value = hello page 1!
[end]
[!page]
    page = PAGE
    page.10 = TEXT
    page.10.value = hello world!
[end]
```

I'm surprised that the docs don't answer this already :S

**edit**

I've tried Andreas Ottos solution, but it still does not seem to work. Here's my example code:

```
lib.content = TEXT
lib.content.value = this text should not get displayed

[globalVar=TSFE:id=1] 
lib.content = TEXT
lib.content.value = this is page 1
[else]
normal_layout = 1
[end]

[globalVar = LIT:1 = {$normal_layout}]
lib.content = TEXT
lib.content.value = this is any other page
[end]
page = PAGE
page.10 < lib.content
```

In theory, this should render 'this is page 1' for page 1 and 'this is any other page' for any other page. But while page 1 gets rendered correctly, this is not the case for the other pages. They get rendered with 'this text should not get displayed'.

Any ideas? I'm using version 7.6. Is that maybe the problem?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Andras Otto No, but I did a workaround in the end. Your solution sadly did not work. In my case, the start page should have been rendered very special but all sub-pages should have been rendered normaly using layouts. But since the sub-pages inherited the parents typo-script I though I need some conditions. But since that did not work, I've moved the start page to a sub-page and made the root-page a link to it. that worked.

Comment: Cool! It is important to let a hint for the future about the solution, thx for sharing it :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** For the first UseCase: 
It is possible with a TypoScript "literal". See a small hint in the [doc here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#globalvar).
And you have to separate the constants from the logic.

So in the constants you have to write:

```
[globalVar=TSFE:id=1]
normal_layout = 0
[else]
normal_layout = 1
[end]
```

And in the setups part you can use this variable:

```
[globalVar = LIT:0 = {$normal_layout}]
    # render special layout for page 1
[end]

[globalVar = LIT:1 = {$normal_layout}] && [globalVar=TSFE:page|layout=1]
# render normal layout 1
[end]

[globalVar = LIT:1 = {$normal_layout}] && [globalVar=TSFE:page|layout=2]
# render normal layout 2
[end]
```

Your second usecase is not really clear but I would recommend to use a base definition of page which is overwritten in the specific cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm having problems using your approach. I've updated my question my my test code.

Comment: I always edited my answer. I did not see, that you are trying to set the constants in the setup, that was the problem. I tested now my solution on a project of mine and it is working. You just need to separate the logic: set the variable (constant) in the constants.ts and use the rendering logic in the setup.ts

Comment: @VanCoding re your use case: are you detecting page types with that condition? Because, backend layouts can handle that nicely. See e.g. http://wiki.wowa-webdesign.de/typo3/backend-layout-typo3-75

Comment: Regrettable this solution is outdated for TYPO3 Version 10

Comment: @Urs the link changed. Did you refer to this: https://wiki.wwagner.info/typo3-snippets/backend-layouts-auswerten-ab-typo3-75 ?